# Binomial distribution for calculating the probability of losing 'N' games

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Joe and Jim play badminton regularly. The probability of Jim losing each game of badminton, independently of all others is 0.05. Jim and Joe play 60 games. Use a suitable approximation, calculate the probability that Jim losing more than 4 games.

Using the following formula, n = 60, x = 4, and p = 0.05, following is my approach. When I use the following in Microsoft Excel, I get the value close to 0. Does that mean, the Jim losing more than 4 games is 100%?

=BINOM.DIST(4,60,0.95,TRUE)

[image: Binomial distribution]

Comment: Note that $1 - 0.05 = 0.95$, not $0.995.$

Comment: @SeanRoberson, Thanks. Still get the same result.

Comment: @user2661923, the probability of Jim winning the game is 95% and not 5%.

Comment: @nsivakr : thanks for the heads-up.  I have deleted my original comment and replaced it:  "Does that mean, that Jim losing more than 4 games is $100\%$?" : No, it means that Jim losing more than 4 games is **close to** $100\%$.

Comment: Thanks @user2661923. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per OP's request:

Probability of Jim losing more than $4$ games is

$$1 - \left[\sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{60}{k} p^k q^{(60 - k)}\right] ~: ~p = (0.05), ~q = 1 - p.$$

Answer (score 1):

The probability of Jim losing *more* than 4 games is equal to: $1-(P_0+P_1+P_2+P_3+P_4)$, where $P_x$ gives us the probability of Jim losing exactly $x$ games, according to the binomial distribution $B(60,5\%)$.

Using the binomial distribution formula in Excel we get:

$P_0\approx0.0461, P_1\approx0.1455, P_2\approx0.2259,P_3\approx0.2298,P_4\approx0.1724$, so the probability of Jim losing more than 4 games out of 60 would be approximately $0.2725$.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei. Need to understand before I can mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @nsivakr Just manually calculate $$1 - \left[\sum_{k=0}^4 \binom{60}{k}p^kq^{(60-k)}\right] ~: ~p = (0.05), q = 1-p.$$

Comment: @user2661923, This makes more sense.

Comment: @user2661923, would you mind posting this as an answer. Will accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: @nsivakr Basically if you want the probability of Jim losing more than 4 games out of 60 games (let’s call this Event A) it’s much easier to compute the complement of the event A, which is the probability of him losing exactly 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 games. I will now edit my answer since I forgot about $P_0$